# Review bug: I pick "leave closed" and it pops up "Nominate for re-opening?"

Tags: bug, status-completed, closed-questions, reviewing

I don't have screen shots, but it's happened twice now, so there must be a bug related to the new close reasons being activated on SF...

When reviewing re-opens, after reading the question and deciding it should stay closed, I click "Leave Closed," and a window pops up asking "Nominate this question for re-opening?"

I think I clicked cancel both times, but I'm not sure.

Either way, it's a bug.

Comment: And seen on meta.SO: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/184603/clicking-leave-closed-shows-the-reopen-pop-up